# How to get a calculated field in SELECT comparing with SYSDATE

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I build this select in Oracle:

```
SELECT DATETYPE_FIELD, DATETYPE_FIELD < SYSDATE AS IS_ON_DATE FROM MYTABLE
```

`DATETYPE_FIELD` is a `DATE` field.
I want to get something like `TRUE/FALSE` in calculated `IS_ON_DATE` field.
USING that select still get an error in ORACLE.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no boolean type in Oracle. You can use 1 or 0 to denote true or false like this:

```
select DATETYPE_FIELD,
    case 
        when DATETYPE_FIELD < SYSDATE
            then 1
        else 0
        end as IS_ON_DATE
from MYTABLE
```

or string "true" and "false"

```
select DATETYPE_FIELD,
    case 
        when DATETYPE_FIELD < SYSDATE
            then 'true'
        else 'false'
        end as IS_ON_DATE
from MYTABLE
```

Comment: Thank you for your  fast answer. This is a good solution for me.

Comment: @user3749378 - Glad it helped.  :-)